# Play audio file on BlackBerry Storm

Tags: blackberry, java-me, media-player

I want to play an mp4 audio file from a URL. This code works for a non-touch device, but I am facing a problem playing on the Storm.

```
Player player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(url);//_source
System.out.println("******************LoginScreen.player" + LoginScreen.player);
playerListener = new MediaPlayerListener();
LoginScreen.player.addPlayerListener(playerListener);
LoginScreen.player.realize();
LoginScreen.player.prefetch();
LoginScreen.player.start();
```

Comment: Hi Archana What kind of are u gettin?

Comment: file is in m4a format, i m not getting the reason why it is not playing. controls stops in create player method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a HTTP location, you should [specify an interface](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0).

For wifi: **;interface=wifi**

Thus your url should be like so:

```
String url= "http://yoursite.com/file.m4a;deviceside=true;interface=wifi";
Player player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(url);//_source
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your file is created with the supported codecs for Blackberry Storm

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/18349/711-01774-123_Supported_Media_Types_on_BlackBerry_Smartphones.pdf

that will be the reason why you can´t reproduce your audio file

> for a MP4 Audio files playing in BlackBerry Storm smartphones the
>   supported codecs are: AAC-LC, AAC+, eAAC+
>   AMR-NB QCELP EVRC

for my experience sometimes you can reproduce files created with other codecs but you will find some problems on playin... =(

hope it helps

Comment: i have checked for codecs of my audio file, All are correct, and also file has not any problem, it is not played only in storm,can u help me in it?